# QED parity invariance and gamma 5

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, parity, dirac-matrices

Why does the invariance of parity of QED indicate that gamma-5 can not appear in Feynman diagrams?

Comment: The claim is false. As $\gamma_5^2=1$, you can always insert factors of $\gamma_5$ here and there.